# document.cookie is not writing on chrome for some key

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

[image: console.log screenshot]

Its really simple, the image above show i execute simple code, insert the string to cookie. but after checking it it is not saved on document.cookie.

This is only occur in my chrome Version 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit), also run my code on firefox and it works normally.

if i set the key name to `rll_grnt` the cookie is not saved, but if its not `rll_grnt` (i try `rll_grntXXX`) its working, i already read documentation and other stackoverflow answer like understanding domain, expires, path, httponly, using comma not semicolon. but i think thats not the problem so it doesn't make any sense.

Notes:

- That console.warn is produced by me
- the screenshot is in chrome console
- Its running on a local server, not files

Comment: FYI: you forgot to paint over your domain on one line